# How to browse and list classic bluetooth devices on IOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

Everyone!

I am developing an ios logging app. It should write about bluetooth devices nearby.

For BLE devices the CoreBluetooth was successfully used.

Any approaches for BT devices (classic bluetooth)?

I tried External Accessory but failed.

```
EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager().connectedAccessories is always empty,
EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager().showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter(nil, completion: nil) shows nothing.
```

I've tested pairing with iphone 5, iphone 6s, and macbook pro late 2013.
Maybe the problem is that macbook isn't an MFI device. Also I didn't put protocol strings in info.plist

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the necessary entitlements. BT 3.x devices manufactured for iPhone only appear if the app in question is entitled (sic!) to.